# Stop pure CSS tabs from scrolling to top of page on selection

Tags: javascript, css

I have a tabbed information box in CSS/HTML which works perfectly, apart from the tab row scrolling to the top of the web page whenever the tab is changed.  It appears that this is a feature of `#` targets.

I have searched for ways to supress this and the consensus appears to be that it can only be done with Javascript.  I have found several suggestions, for example adding:

```
onclick='e.preventDefault();'
```

or

`onclick='return false;'`  - A no-no apparently.

However whenever I add an `onclick=` to the tab's `<a>` element it stops the tabs from working at all, rather than only supressing the screen jump.

The HTML for the tabs is as follows (I have omitted the CSS as I can't see that it is too relevant as the tabs look and behave fine, I can post it if required):

```
<div class=detailtabs>
 <div id=tab1> <a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
  <div>
    <h2 style="color:#ff0000;">This is Tab 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non nibh mauris. </p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id=tab2> <a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
  <div>
     <h2 style="color:#ff0000;">This is Tab 2</h2>
     <p>Morbi molestie molestie felis, non vehicula urna. </p> 
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id=tab3> <a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
  <div>
      <h2 style="color:#ff0000;">This is Tab 3</h2>
      <p>Nam accumsan hendrerit lorem, eu elementum sapien faucibus a. </p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id=tab4> <a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a>
  <div>
    <h2 style="color:#ff0000;">This is Tab 4</h2>
    <p>Nulla eget sollicitudin diam. Quisque dictum suscipit aliquet. </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I know I must be missing something very obvious. Perhaps it is my (mis)use of the JavaScript.  It tends to be quoted by people as a function, not in the context of the HTML in question.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: give us a working example in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/gentuqu5/ I have added a div around it to simulate the box being further down the page, it seems to behave better in the jsfiddle sandbox, but it still jumps.

Comment: Check This out, it may help. You use checkboxs instead of hrefs. http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-slideshow-without-page-jump

Comment: Many thanks for the link @Neoaptt, after a bit of playing around I've used radio buttons and it works much better then `#` and `:target`.  If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This out, it may help. You use checkboxs instead of hrefs.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-slideshow-without-page-jump

Comment: In case anyone is interested, this is the end result: https://jsfiddle.net/SandwichUK/ecu7xwwL/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of suppressing native behavior why don't you change to a placeholder link by removing the `href` attribute all together.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

> href
>
> This was the single required attribute for anchors defining a
> hypertext source link, but is no longer required in HTML5. Omitting
> this attribute creates a placeholder link.

Comment: Thanks @pherris, I will check that out.  Won't losing the `#tab1, #tab2, #tab3` hrefs lose the targeting of which tab to display though?

Comment: Yes, you are right - it wasn't clear to me (before the fiddle) that the css :target was used to show/hide tabs. Neoaptt suggested not using `a` tags as well (checkboxes will work as per the link he posted) - this is the general approach - don't try to change the behavior of an `a` tag, use something else.

Comment: Many thanks @pherris I've followed the advice and moved away from the `<a>` tags.